# new value to variable powershell

Tags: powershell

I've got a program that collects information about a computer and displays some data. But i cannot figure out how to get a new value on my variable if i want to collect info about another computer. Below are some of my code.

The variable containing computer value is DatorNamn.

Any Suggestions on how to get a new value into that variable?

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("system.windows.form")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null

#test av variable

$DatorNamn = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Skriv in DatorNamn', 'DatorNamn', "$env:Computername") | Write-Output

#Skriver Formen

$Form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(450,415)
    $form1.text = "Scripts Target:$DatorNamn"
    $form1.BackColor = "darkgray"
    $form1.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
    $form1.MinimizeBox = $true
    $form1.MaximizeBox = $true
    $Form1.ControlBox = $true
    $form1.Font = "Segoe UI"

        #Skriver Knapp byt DatorNamn

$KnappBdata = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $KnappBdata.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,152)
    $KnappBdata.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,32)
    $KnappBdata.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $KnappBdata.ForeColor = "black"
    $KnappBdata.BackColor = "White"
    $KnappBdata.Text = "Byt Dator"
    $KnappBdata.Add_click({
    $outputBox.Text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Skriv in DatorNamn', 'DatorNamn', "$env:COMPUTERNAME") | Write-Output


    })
    $Form1.Controls.Add($KnappBdata)

[void] $Form1.ShowDialog()
´´´
```

Comment: So your current script works correctly but you want to know how you would go about doing this multiple times?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want!

Answer (score 0):

You have everything you need: The Button event needs to refresh the text of a GUI-object or a variable whenever it is pressed. I tweeked your exampl a little. try pressing the button and changing the text multiple times:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("system.windows.form")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null

#test av variable

$DatorNamn = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Skriv in DatorNamn', 'DatorNamn', "$env:Computername") | Write-Output

#Skriver Formen

$Form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(450,415)
    $form1.text = "Scripts Target:$DatorNamn"
    $form1.BackColor = "darkgray"
    $form1.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
    $form1.MinimizeBox = $true
    $form1.MaximizeBox = $true
    $Form1.ControlBox = $true
    $form1.Font = "Segoe UI"

        #Skriver Knapp byt DatorNamn

$KnappBdata = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $KnappBdata.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,152)
    $KnappBdata.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,32)
    $KnappBdata.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $KnappBdata.ForeColor = "black"
    $KnappBdata.BackColor = "White"
    $KnappBdata.Text = "Byt Dator"
    $KnappBdata.Add_click({
        # since you don't have $outputBox it will update the button
        $KnappBdata.Text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Skriv in DatorNamn', 'DatorNamn', "$env:COMPUTERNAME") | Write-Output
    })
    $Form1.Controls.Add($KnappBdata)

[void] $Form1.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thanks, i understand. But how to change something else than the button? I want to change value on variable DatarNamn

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of control loop to be able to repeat a task multiple times.

Since your interaction method includes a cancel button, we can test if the response from `InputBox` is blank before doing the task. In prose, it would be "while a particular condition is true, keep repeating a task".

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null

while ($Var = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Description', 'Title', "default")) {
    Write-Host "You typed: $Var"
}
```

If you run this, then it will continue to run the commands within the curly brackets until you enter nothing or click the cancel button.